# Change PFUser Information with Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Im working on building a small app using Swift and the Parse platform.

Im wondering about how to add additional data to the PFUser Class with the Parse platform. I have gone and created a new Column in the Parse Data browser under the Users tab with the key "Name". However, the code here doesn't seem to add the string containing the full name of the user (Taken from Facebook) to the new Column in the Parse Data browser

```
func saveUserNameToParse() {

      var user = PFUser.currentUser()
      user!.setObject(self.userName, forKey: "Name")
      user!.saveInBackground()
}
```

I'm really lost and I may not have even formulated this question entirely correctly. If you know of a way to do this I would really appreciate it, I have been stuck on this for hours. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any error? Is the use logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to save a user:

```
PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result["email"], forKey: "email")
PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result["name"], forKey: "name")
PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result["gender"], forKey: "gender")
PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result["city"],   forKey: "city")
PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result["zipCode"],   forKey: "zipCode")

PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if (success != nil) {
        println("GOOD JOB!")

    } else {
        println("BAD NEWS!: \(error)")
    }
}
```

If you need to save additional data to the user's table then you can do that also, it works like this:

this is from Parse's website and it's current, this is how you update an object so basically you would updating the user table with entries that you just added a column for:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
  (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
    println(error)
  } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
    gameScore["score"] = 1338
    gameScore.saveInBackground()
  }
}
```

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide